# Еhere was an error while adding url to test

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

When I transfer to the test url, an error pops up:

> Reverse for 'movie' not found. 'movie' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Here is my self test:

```
class BooksApiTestCase(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.movie_1 = Movie.objects.create(title="terminator", year="1990", rating="5",url="retminator")
    self.movie_2 = Movie.objects.create(title="robocop", year="1991", rating="4",url="robocop")
    self.movie_3 = Movie.objects.create(title="rembo", year="1992", rating="3",url='rembo')

def test_get(self):
    url = reverse('movie')
    print(url)
    response = self.client.get(url)
    serializer_data = MovieListSerializer([self.movie_1, self.movie_2, self.movie_3], many=True).data
    self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_200_OK, response.status_code)
    self.assertEqual(serializer_data, response.data)
```

Here is my self url:

```
    urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
path("movie/", views.MovieViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Andrew and Welcome to StackOverflow.

To use `reverse()` you have to properly set the view's name in the `urlpatterns`

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    path("movie/", views.MovieViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}, name='movie')
]),
```

Refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)